# How do i display one dataGridview in two panels

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to display a DataGridView (one object) on two panels.

However, the DataGridView is displayed only on the last panel (last Add to panel)

How can i display one DataGridView on two panels?

```cs
this.dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dataGridView2.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
this.dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.dataGridView2.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.matrial_Code,
        this.material_Name,
        this.material_Spec});
this.dataGridView2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 66);
this.dataGridView2.Name = "dataGridView2";
this.dataGridView2.ReadOnly = true;
this.dataGridView2.RowTemplate.Height = 27;
this.dataGridView2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(398, 456);
this.dataGridView2.TabIndex = 2;
this.dataGridView2.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView2_CellContentClick);
this.dataGridView2.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView2_DoubleClick);

this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView2); //No Display
this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView2); //Display
```

Comment: And why do you want to do that??  A control can only have a *single parent**

Comment: Q:How can something be at multiple places at the same time? A:Clone it

Comment: try to create datagridviews dynamically.